# Long-running jupyter notebook can't connect. Don't want to lose all my work

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I've had a jupyter notebook running for a week training a ML model. Usually I can tap the dropdown "Reconnect" when I need to check in on it. Now jupyter just started giving an error saying it can't connect. I don't want to restart it and lose all my progress, then likely have the same thing happen again!

When I checked the Kernel it was giving this error:
SSL Error on 15 ('***.***.***.***', 55359): [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN] sslv3 alert certificate unknown (_ssl.c:997)

I am hosting this on AWS and have just ignored the certificate warning.

How can I reconnect to this thing without restarting it?

Answer (score 0):

I found it! This worked in Chrome and might work in other browsers too.

1. Duplicate the tab.
2. In the new tab you'll see the SSL warning saying the page is insecure. Hit "Advanced" and allow the connection.
3. Close that new tab, go back to the broken tab and reconnect. It should work now.

Comment: It is also safe to close or refresh a tab with a jupyter notebook. The notebook keeps running